# How do I set the String text to change into a different quote after every 10 seconds?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java and I don't know how to make it where the String text changes to a different quote every 10 seconds. I want to make 10 texts that displays one every 10 seconds.

I want to create more strings and find an efficient way to add it to the Graphics g component and change the quote because i can only do one atm.

```
public class GardenOfEden extends Canvas
{     
    String quote = "I can do everything through Christ who gives me strength. (Phillippians 4:13)";        
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {       
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;//graphics2D class        
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2.drawString(quote,550,550);         
    }    
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at [How to use Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Timer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

The fastest and easiest way to schedule tasks in Swing is to use a `javax.swing.Timer`. You can find a simple example below.

```
new Timer(() -> {
   // change your strings here
}, 10000).start();
```

If you, for some reason, want your timer to wait for an arbitrary amount before actually starting after you start it, you can use `Timer#setInitialDelay(int initialDelay)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `javax.swing.Timer`

For example:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Random;


public class GardenOfEden extends Frame {

    private static final String[] QUOTES;

    static {
        QUOTES = new String[10];
        QUOTES[0] = "Quote1";
        QUOTES[1] = "Quote2";
        QUOTES[2] = "Quote3";
        QUOTES[3] = "Quote4";
        QUOTES[4] = "Quote5";
        QUOTES[5] = "Quote6";
        QUOTES[6] = "Quote7";
        QUOTES[7] = "Quote8";
        QUOTES[8] = "Quote9";
        QUOTES[9] = "Quote10";
    }

    private static final int DELAY = 2000;

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    private Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == timer) {
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    public GardenOfEden() {
        super("Quotes Example");
        setSize(1024, 768);
        setVisible(true);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GardenOfEden();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;//graphics2D class
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2.drawString(getQuote(),550,550);
    }

    private String getQuote() {
        int i = RANDOM.nextInt(QUOTES.length);
        return QUOTES[i];
    }
}
```